# Ssis code to do DNS lookup

Tags: c#, ssis, dns

I am converting a perl script on Linux to an ssis package running on Windows. I have attempted to do DNS lookup via `DNS.Gethostentry` but cannot get it to work. When I out this into the c#,  I get incorrect function types. Even when I recast these,  it fails. Does anyone help with this interface? I tried using the example on msdn with a string input parm.

Comment: Please provide a more complete question - show your code, show the error messages and warnings

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/DnsClient provides C# with DNS lookup features. Try it out, I have no idea what SSIS actually requires or works with in terms of .net framework, but mybe it works